Fastify decorate not registering middleware
I am trying to create middleware to check the JWT that is passed through on route calls. I have followed the JWT middleware guide and converted the code to typescript as its all in vanilla JS. I am getting an issue where fastify.decorate doesn't seem to register the new decorator that i want to call on requests.
authMiddleware.ts
import fp from "fastify-plugin";
import fastifyJwt from "@fastify/jwt";
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from "fastify";

const authenticatePlugin = fp<FastifyInstance>(async (fastify, opts) => {
  fastify.register(fastifyJwt, {
    secret: "secret",
  });

  fastify.decorate(
    "authenticate",
    async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
      try {
        await request.jwtVerify();
      } catch (err) {
        reply.send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});

export default authenticatePlugin;

Index.ts(entry point to api)
const server = fastify({
  logger: pino({ level: "info" }),
});

server.register(authenticatePlugin);
server.register(db, { uri });
server.register(MatchRoute);
server.register(AuthRoutes);

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await server.listen({ port: 7000 });
    console.log("Server started successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    server.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
start();

and then my route where my issue is:
  fastify.post<{ Body: MatchAttributes }>(
    "/matches",
    {
      onRequest: [fastify.authenticate],
    },
    async (request, reply) => {

On fastify.authenticate, i get the error:
Property 'authenticate' does not exist on type 'FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>'.ts(2339)

How is the MatchRoute function exported? EDIT: It is a TS error, that code would work in vanilla JS

To avoid this error, you need to "tell" the typescript compiler that authenticate is a property of the FastifyInstance interface using declaration merging:
declare module "fastify" {
 interface FastifyInstance {
   authenticate: (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => Promise<void>;
 }
}

Without it, the typescript compiler fails to recognize that the authenticate property was added to fastify using decorate.
See a more detailed example in fastify documentation: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/TypeScript/#plugins
